# Привязка домена

Tags: ip, домен, dns, хостинг

Использую сервис teamlab.com. Есть ненужный домен, который хочу привязать. На самом сайте все готово, а вот у регистратора не пойму что делать. На teamlab.com написано:

Примечание: чтобы задать свое доменное имя, Вы можете использовать одну из следующих опций (первая предпочтительнее): Добавьте DNS-запись типа CNAME, как например: team.ourcompany.com - intranet.teamlab.com Добавьте DNS-запись типа A, как например: team.ourcompany.com - 184.73.209.189 (IP-адрес).

У регистратора есть 4 поля "Имя DNS-сервера" и 4 поля "IP DNS-сервера". Что куда писать, подскажите пожалуйста, никак не могу понять

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите другие возможности по управлению доменом. То, что вы видите, это управление DNS-серверами. А вам нужно управление зоной. Там прямо прописываются записи типа CNAME или A. Должно быть [страница](https://pdd.yandex.ru/help/section9/) (у каждого регистратора она может быть своя) управления записями. Просто поищите ее у своего регистратора.

Comment: У меня были указаны dns сервера хостера, а уже в панели хостера я сменил CNAME